# A limit computation Involving continued product

Tags: calculus, limits, analysis

Assume that $A$ is a constant that very close to 3, does the limit exist and if so, how to compute it?

$\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n-1}\left(A-\cos \left(\frac{i}{n} 2 \pi\right)\right)}{\prod_{i=0}^{n-2}\left(A-\cos \left(\frac{i}{n-1} 2 \pi\right)\right)}$

Comment: Polynomials in variable $A$ that you obtain when you expand the numerator or the denominator are connected to polynomials $\Psi_n(x)$ as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_polynomial_of_2cos(2pi/n))

Comment: We can show that, for a sufficiently well-behaved $f$, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(
 \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 1} f {\left( \frac j n \right)} -
 \sum_{j = 0}^{n - 2} f {\left( \frac j {n - 1} \right)} \right) =
\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx.$$
A cleaner way is to find $a$ s.t. $|1 - a e^{2 \pi i j/n}|^2 = 2 a (A - \cos(2 \pi j/n))$ and to evaluate
$$\prod_{j = 0}^{n - 1} \left( 1 - a e^{2 \pi i j/n} \right)$$
(say, by viewing the product as a polynomial in $a$ and finding its roots).